# 3 hash functions to best hash sliding window strings for a bloom filter with minimum collisions

Tags: c#

I need 3 hash functions to hash strings of a sliding window moving over a text, to be used later to search within a bloom vector. I'm using C# in my programming

I read something about rolling hash functions and cyclic polynomials, they are used for sliding window applications. But really, I did not find any codes, they are just descriptions

So please, if anyone have any idea about 3 best C# hash functions to use with sliding window strings of fixed size (5-char), that consume less time and have minimum number of collisions, either they are rolling hash functions or others, please help me with some C# codes or links to hash functions names

The strings are all hex, I mean consist of (0-9) and (A-F) capital letters only, along with the dash character (-) ... for example

my string can be AB-2C-65-ED-65

Duaa

Comment: What distribution do the characters in the string have? If there are few enough characters then you may be able to compute a lossless hash over five characters.

Answer (score 0):

Alpha chars only?  Upper and lower?  If you have just 5 case insensitive [a-z] chars, you can pack them into 5*5 = 25 bits phenomenally quickly with bit shifting since `26 < 2^5`.  So a 32-bit int could pack the entire string with zero hash collisions.

**[EDIT]**

OK, now that you've clarified the input.

[0-9], [A-Z] + ['-'] is 37 characters... just over the 32 character limit for 5 bits.  So, you'll need 6 bits to store each char.  Luckily, even with 5 chars, that's only `6*5 = 30` bits total, so you can completely pack the entire string into a 32 bit int, and won't even need to fiddle the sign bit, so you'll have a very fast, completely lossless (zero collision) hash code that uniquely identifies each string... that could even be reversed!  All numbers will be positive, so you could assign some other meaning to the sign bit if desired.

Below is your new function to pack 5 characters in the range [0-9], [a-z] + ['-'] into an int.  You will first need to take the Hex string and dehex it back to its normal state, and then run it through the bit twiddling below.

```
string c; //This is your text to hash.

public override int GetHashCode()
{
    if (c.Length > 5) throw new InvalidOperationException("Sliding window string too long");

    const char dash = (char)45;
    //Pack all characters right-aligned within the int
    return (c[0]-dash << 24) | (c[1]-dash << 18) | (c[2]-dash << 12) | (c[3]-dash << 6) | c[4]-dash;
}
```

Note: You can also safely use a few other characters between ASCII 45 and ASCII 109 like: "`./:;<=>?[\]^_`" without modifying this code.

Comment: Really; The strings are all hex, I mean consist of (0-9) and (A-F) capital letters only, along with the dash character (-) ... for example my string can be AB-2C-65-ED-65 Can your hash function be helpfull for sliding window, I mean to benifit from
the previous window hash, to save more time, please and thank you alot

Comment: You probably won't even need to consider optimizing the function above any further.  Those bit shifting operators run blazingly fast.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but I want to notify you that may range is dash, [0-9] and [A-F] not [a-z] , so they are 17 cahr not 37 char

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but I want to notify you that may range is dash, [0-9] and [A-F] not [a-z] , so they are 17 cahr not 37 char, Now I do not know if your answer will change or not ? Also, I'm dehex each 2-hex into their int value , and treat them as one value, and the dash can be ignored .... what do you think .... is it an efficient way to hash or it can be done better .... please help me and thanks alot dear

Comment: Hi Duaa - Wow, that changes things a lot!  Can you lose the dash to get down to 16 bits instead of 17?  Regardless, the function above will work fine, as it accepts A-Z, which includes A-F.  If you think that you would add another character (making it 6) instead of additional letters, I'll write the function up to work with the 17 characters you use, and to allow up to 6 of them (instead of 5).  Otherwise, the function will work great!

Comment: Yes, sure I can lose the dash, so my range is [0-9] and [A-F] capitals only, so my (4-char) string will be 4ADE8C39 .... but what I'm wondering about is whether to use each hex char as it is in the loop or dehex every two hex char to its int or ascii value before? but if I dehex every two char into its ascii, I may get all ascii char, so my range will not be 16 char only, it will be all 256 ascii ... so I'm thinking to use hex char as it is without dehex, so my string will be 8-hex, each one can be represented by 4 bits (4*8=32).. what do you think? which is best to use dehex or without dehex?

Comment: Did you get my point ? please help me which is best to use and how will the hash function change now ?

Comment: Hi Duaa - If you're just working with valid HEX values (no dash), each value will fit into 16 values by definition.  That's just 4 bits, so you could pack 8 of them into a 32 bit integer hash value.  However, you don't need my fancy bit-packing loop to do it.  .Net natively converts 32 bit hash values to ints.  For instance, your 4ADE8C39 already IS a valid hash value.  In decimal, it's 1256098873.  You can use int.TryParse(YourString, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber) to go from your Hex string to an int.  Bam!  Done.  Doesn't get much faster than that!

Comment: By the way, your hash values will be sliding windows as well, but it will be at the bit level, so you won't "see" the sliding when you view the bits at ints.

Comment: Thanks for your reply ... but I think in this way if I have 4000 hex string and I need to represent their hashes in a bloom vector to check any string existance, so I will need a 2^32 bit hash index ... is it true ? Is there a way to reduce the structure size that represent their hashes to less than 2^32 bit (each bit represent the int hash index) ?